# How to implement callbacks with interface

Tags: c++, interface, callback

I have a class which needs more callbacks..
I am trying to implement them with an interface:

```
class CallbacksInterface
{
public:
     virtual bool mycallback1() = 0;
     virtual bool mycallback2() = 0;
     virtual bool mycallback3() = 0;
};

Class BusImplementation{
public:
    addRequest(bool (CallbacksInterface::*callback)());

}
```

Callback is parameter for **addRequest()** method and is defined as **pointer to interface method**.
So I want to add request..

```
//class with callbacks
class Main:CallbacksInterface{
public:
      bool mycallback1(){..};
      bool mycallback2(){..};
      bool mycallback3(){..};
      //.. 
}

BusImplemantation bus;
Main main;   

bus.addRequest(main.mycallback1);          
bus.addRequest(main.mycallback2);
bus.addRequest(main.mycallback3);
```

But I cant pass a callback into my BusImplemantation class

```
error: argument of type 'bool (Main::)()' does not match 'bool (CallbacksInterface::*)()'
```

I think there is a solution with templates, but I am programming embedded devices and my compiler is limited.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have a callback interface representing a single function, and pass pointers to different implementations of that? Or even better, use ``std::functions``?

Comment: Does it help if you use public inheritance, i.e. `class Main: public CallbacksInterface`?

Comment: Just in case you're using the type names from your actual software project - there's a typo in `BusImplemantation`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to define a single interface type representing a function:

```
struct ICallback
{
  virtual bool operator()() const = 0;
};
```

and implement it as many times as necessary:

```
struct Foo : ICallback
{
  virtual bool operator()() const { return true;}
};

struct Bar : ICallback
{
  virtual bool operator()() const { return false;}
};
```

then your bus implementation can take callback interfaces:

```
class BusImplemantation{
public:
    void addRequest(const ICallback* callback) { .... }
};
```

then

```
BusImplemantation bus;
Foo foo;  // can be called: bool b = foo();
Bar bar;   // can be called: bool b = bar();

bus.addRequest(&foo);          
bus.addRequest(&bar);
```

You could also investigate using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and avoiding the common interface altogether.

Comment: seems interesting, I have to try it! This operator() has specific meaning? Its new for me. thanks

Comment: @Meloun the ``operator()`` makes an instance "callable". I added some comments in the code. If you have an ``ICallback*``, you can call the operator like this: ``pCakkBack->operator()();``

Comment: What about **(*pCallBack)();** ? seems nicer for me.

Comment: disadvantage: If callback is in some class, you cant within callback access to this class and members. If callback would be not class, but only method you can. (inner class vs. method)

Comment: @Meloun why can't you call class members and access data within the callback? I can't see it.

Comment: **to juanchopanza:** http://pastebin.com/XHgBiAQx If callback would be only method you can access to myvar.

Answer (score 1):

I also strongly suggest going with an abstract interface. However, if you really want the original approach for some reason, you need something like this:

```
void addRequest(bool (CallbacksInterface::*callback)(), CallbacksInterface* pTarget) {...}
...
bus.addRequest(&CallbacksInterface::mycallback1, &main); 
// ! Not &Main::mycallback1 - that wouldn't compile
...
// calling a callback
(pTarget->*callback)();
```